# WebStorm Live Edit does not work for JavaScript, any solutions?

Tags: javascript, debugging, intellij-idea, webstorm, liveedit

I am having this problem after the 25 January update.

When I edit files on an HTML document the Live Edit detects changes and makes changes to the browser. But in case of JavaScript the changes are not applied unless I refresh the browser (there is no point of live edit if I have to refresh the browser).

[image: WebStorm settings window]

Answer (score 1):

It's not a regression, it was always working this way: unlike changes in embedded JavaScript, changes in 'external' (linked) JavaScript code don't cause immediate page reloading: new code is loaded to the browser instantly, but the results of the change will be visible only when you do something to trigger this new code. For example if you change the `onClick` handler and write new text in `alert()`, you will see the new text after the click without reloading the page. Same for functions triggered by timer, for example. But if the JavaScript code is executed only on page load (and not on certain event), you have to manually reload the page to see the results - Live Edit doesn't force new code execution, it changes the code and not application state.

Comment: so it is not like vs code live server? 

i had the impression that it was loading js previously, before the update, tho not sure i used it for this kind of low lvl JS

Comment: no, it's not like a live server where the page reloading is implemented on server end. Live Edit works regardless of the server the app is hosted on, and it uses hotswapping technology rather than page reloading